# Angular Template integrated with Neovis.js takes 20 minutes to compile

Tags: angular, neo4j, angular-cli

Can some one help me .
I am using Neo4j application to build and integrate it to an angular and nodejs app.
I am using Core UI - angular template. It complies within 3 minutes. (Or any other template). However, when i include the Neovis.js that is Neo4j app library , it takes around 20 minutes to compile.

I used -

```
 ng build --watch
```

And i get errors like -

```
 ERROR in /home/dell/Neo4j-5/src/assets/neovis.js 
(36620,54): Property 'hierarchical_sort_method' does not exist on type 
'object'.

ERROR in /home/dell/Neo4j-5/src/assets/neovis.js 
(36647,118): Property 'values' does not exist on type 
'ObjectConstructor'.

ERROR in /home/dell/Neo4j-5/src/assets/neovis.js 
(36648,118): Property 'values' does not exist on type 
'ObjectConstructor'.

 ERROR in /home/dell/Neo4j-5/src/assets/neovis.js (35241,17297): 
 Property 'parse' does not exist on type '() => void'.

 ERROR in /home/dell/Neo4j-5/src/assets/neovis.js (35241,17388): 
 Property 'check' does not exist on type '() => void'.

 ERROR in /home/dell/Neo4j-5/src/assets/neovis.js (35241,17478): 
 Property 'getSuggestion' does not exist on type '() => void'.
```

Which don't come coming when i don't use CoreUI or any other Akveo templates.

.angular-cli.json

```
{
"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-alpha.6",
    "name": "coreui-angular"
  },
   "apps": [
    {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "assets": [
            "assets"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "prefix": "app",
        "styles": [
            "scss/style.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.min.js",
            "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"
        ],
        "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
        "environments": {
            "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
            "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
    }
  ],
    "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
        "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
    },
    "lint": [
    {
        "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
        "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
        "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
   ],
   "test": {
    "karma": {
        "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
   },
   "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "serve": {
        "port": 4200,
        "host": "localhost"
    }
    }
  }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the template. Or use the command -

```
 ng serve --aot=true
```

But mostly this command requires angular6 cli - though not sure.